# mypy reports error in Dict outside class but not inside

Tags: python, mypy

When I use a dict where members have different types, mypy accepts my type definitions within the class but not outside.

The access of member 'first' in

```
ExampleClass.__str__()
```

does *not* produce an error from mypy when I iterate over it.

But when I get same data outside the class, iterating over 'first' causes mypy to generate an error.

What is going on?

```python
from typing import Union, List, Dict
from collections import namedtuple

class ExampleClass:
    PrimeOption = namedtuple('PrimeOption', ['value1', 'value2'])
    PrimeList = List[PrimeOption]
    ExampleData = Dict[str, Union[bool, PrimeOption]]

    def __init__(self):
        self.data:ExampleData = {'flag':False,
                                 'first': [ExampleClass.PrimeOption.value1]}

    def get(self) -> ExampleData:
        return self.data

    def __str__(self):
        t = self.get()
        out = 'ExampleClass:'
        for i in t['first']:
            out += str(i)
        return out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = ExampleClass()
    print(obj)

    t = obj.get()
    for i in t['first']:
        print(i)
```

This produces one error from mypy:

```
$ mypy union.py
union.py:33: error: Item "bool" of "Union[bool, PrimeOption]" has no attribute "__iter__" (not iterable)
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I am using python3.8.8 and mypy 0.812.

**Edit**:
This needs to work with python3.6.

Comment: what you probably need is a [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict)

Comment: Some targets of this code use python 3.6 (which doesn't have TypedDict). Using ExampleData = TypedDict('ExampleData', {'flag': bool, 'first': PrimeOption}) does fix error.

Comment: `TypedDict` was backported to Python3.6 with [`typing_extensions` package](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions)

Comment: I will flag the comment of [Azat Ibrakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5997596/azat-ibrakov) as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Azat Ibrakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5997596/azat-ibrakov) says, in a comment above, `TypedDict` is ported to python3.6 in the [typing extension](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) package.

By adding

```
from typing_extensions import TypedDict
```

and replacing `ExampleData` with

```
    ExampleData = TypedDict('ExampleData', {'flag': bool, 'first': PrimeOption})
```

no error is reported.

The changes work for python3.6 and python3.8.

Comment: we can also add in `requirements.txt` (or whatever dependencies list is used) line with [environment marker](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/) like `typing-extensions; python_version < '3.8'` and after that import `try:     from typing import TypedDict\ except ImportError:    from typing_extensions import TypedDict`